# ngModel is reflecting to all textareas

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have multiple textareas (looping with ngFor and adding new divs with textareas inside). What i need is for every textarea to have separate ngModel and i don't want to directly bind this to property from object in dataArray - for example:

```
[(ngModel)]='data.note' or [(ngModel)]='data.feedback' .
```

This works but I don't have feedback property in dataArray so it won't for work for second textarea.

For example with my current implementation change in one textarea is reflecting in all other textareas. I tried with index approach but getting error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

<div *ngFor="let data of dataArray; let index=index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
<div class="card-body">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="form-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="note" [(ngModel)]='selectedNote' class="form-control"
              rows="2"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="feedback" [(ngModel)]='selectedFeedback' class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

With current code if i add some text in first textarea with name 'note' that change is reflected for all textareas with name 'note'. As mentioned tried with adding

```
[(ngModel)]='selectedFeedback[index]' but i am getting error.
```

Also tried with giving different names to textareas:

```
<textarea name="note{{index}}" [(ngModel)]='dataArray[index]' rows="2"></textarea> OR

  <textarea name="note{{index}}" [(ngModel)]='selectedNote' rows="2"></textarea>
```

but change is reflecting for each textarea again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with any array, I am using data(n) function to return an Array of length n. In this example it's just for iteration

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data(8); let i = index">
  <textarea [(ngModel)]='values[i]'></textarea>
</div>

// To reflect changes
<div *ngFor="let item of data(8); let i = index">
  <div>{{ values[i] }}</div>
</div>
```

With TS

```
export class AppComponent  {

  values = [];

  data(n) {
    return Array(n);
  }
}
```

Working example in [Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sytwhv)

Comment: This works good. I suppose for now will use this approach but i was thinking there is better way from angular to handle this. Thanks @Debojyoti!

Comment: Which part you want to improve? Can you please specify?
values[] array or iteration process (let item of data(8)) ? @Bukic

Comment: This works perfectly but i was thinking that we don't need to do this (to create new array with index). I was thinking that we can use directly in html with index and use index to ngModel and name attribute but it seems it is not working good, at least for me :)

Comment: If you want to use different variables for each element's ngModel directive, then named attribute cannot work. It's not possible to distinguish between them. But if you get any better solution please update in this post :)

Answer (score 1):

ngModel binds with the name property. So if you want to use multiple textarea try using different name attribute. You can iterate over like -

```
<ng-container *ngIf="let data of dataArray; index as i">
   <textarea name="feedback_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]='selectedFeedback' class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Tried that but change is reflecting for all textareas again :(

Comment: can you please add you component.ts also. May be something is wrong in the logic.

Comment: If you are still facing the issue, its better to Use reactive FormArray. It might help in you scenario. May be this link might help you - https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2